# How to mock Routing state in angular for unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, angular7, karma-jasmine, angular-router

I am writing unit tests for my component but having trouble in creating the instance of the component and showing following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'patientId' of null
```

I have tried mocking all the providers including router and active router
here is how I am calling the component:

```js
  public onSelectedOrganizationInsurance(organizationInsurance: OrganizationInsurance) {
    this.router.navigate(['../search-insurance-plan'], {
      relativeTo: this.activatedRoute,
      state: {
        selectedOrganizationInsurance: organizationInsurance,
        patientId: this.patientId
      }
    });
```

My component.ts is

```js
export class PatientInsurancePlanSearchComponent implements OnInit {

  private patientId: number = -1;
  public selectedOrganizationInsurance: OrganizationInsurance;
  public organizationInsurancePlans$: Observable<OrganizationInsurancePlan[]>;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private biilingHttpService: BillingHttpService
  ) {
    this.selectedOrganizationInsurance = new OrganizationInsurance();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.patientId = history.state.patientId as number;
    this.selectedOrganizationInsurance = history.state.selectedOrganizationInsurance as OrganizationInsurance;
    this.organizationInsurancePlans$ = this.biilingHttpService.getOrganizationInsurancePlans(this.selectedOrganizationInsurance.id);
  }
```

spec.ts

```js
class FakeInsurancePlanSearchComponent {
  @Input() public organizationInsurancePlans: OrganizationInsurancePlan[] = [];
  @Input() public selectedOrganizationInsurance: OrganizationInsurance;
  }
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ PatientInsurancePlanSearchComponent
      , FakeInsurancePlanSearchComponent ],
      imports: [
        StoreModule.forRoot({}),
        HttpClientModule,
        RouterTestingModule,
      ],
      providers: [
        Store,
        {
          provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: {
            state: of({ selectedorganizationInsurancePlan: 'AETNA'})
        }
      },
      BillingHttpService
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PatientInsurancePlanSearchComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

Kindly guide me whats I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

you can access your routing state via "Location" injection of @angular/common.
Like this:

```js
constructor(private readonly location: Location) {}
    
ngOnInit() {
  this.patientId = this.location.getState().patientId as number;
}
```

now you can create a spy on location in your unit test:

```js
let location: Location;

beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [
      PatientInsurancePlanSearchComponent,
      FakeInsurancePlanSearchComponent,
    ],
    imports: [StoreModule.forRoot({}), HttpClientModule, RouterTestingModule],
    providers: [Store, BillingHttpService],
  }).compileComponents();
}));

beforeEach(() => {
  location = TestBed.inject(Location);
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PatientInsurancePlanSearchComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  fixture.detectChanges();
});

it('should create', () => {
  spyOn(location, 'getState').and.returnValue(yourObject);
  expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});
```